# how to write 2D char array into a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

How do I write a 2D char array to a file. I searched for the solution everywhere, but didn't find an answer.

```
void printDATA(){
String[][] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length, String[][].class);
char[][] charArray = new char[stringArray.length][stringArray[0].length];
            for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < stringArray[0].length; j++)
                {
                    charArray[i][j] = stringArray[i][j].charAt(0);
                }
            }
        File file = new File("result.doc");
        try {
            //FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(file);//Gives error
            PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(file);//This also gives error
            fout.write(charArray);
            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Writer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) does not support writing arrays of arrays. Only `int` (which should really be a `char`), `String`, or `char[]`. Loop over the arrays to write.

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    fout.write(charArray[i]);
}
```

You will probably want to throw in newline characters as well.

Comment: Actually i really want to print either 2D char array or 2D string array. Is there any alternative method..??

Comment: Not using common APIs. It would help to explain what you mean by printing a 2D array. Take this array: `String[][] test = { { "foo", "bar", "baz" }, { "1", "12", "123" }, { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox" } };`. What are you expecting the program to print?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
for(int i =0;i< 1st dimension; i++)
   { for(int j =0;j< 2nd dimension; j++)
        {
          write (array[i][j])
          write (some symbol)
        }
  write (some other symbol)
   }
```

Then you will need to remember the delimiting symbols when you want to read from the file.

Then you will need to read the whole file as String and split it using the 1st symbol then the 2nd symbol.

For example, lets take the following 2D array:

apple orange pineapple.

banana tomato grape.

You can write it to a file as 1D string as:
apple,orange,pineapple;banana,tomato,grape;

Then when you read the file as string, you split on ";" and get:
apple,orange,pineapple
banana,tomato,grape

then split each one at "," and re-build your 2D array.

Comment: That is if you don't want to use any API or complex code

Comment: @M I think file handling using  FileWriter only support one dimensional char array. Any other OutputStream method or alternative method..?